# Checking if null or whitespace in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have been in the process of teaching myself Vue.js and really like it so far. I have a project that I finally get the chance to use it on. I am creating a form and wanting to do some validations. I am used to the C# way of doing things, such as `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` that just hits everything in one swoop. I haven't found a way to do that in Vue yet, if even possible. I do know of simpler ways to do it in regular javascript

This is my app and data

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return { 
            errors: [],
            parentInfo: {
                name: null,
                address: null,
                city: null,
                state: null,
                zip: null,
                primaryPhone: null,
                secondaryPhone: null
            }  
        }
    }
...
```

Here are my validations for the form. This still does not catch if they add a whitespace to every field.

```
checkParentInfo: function () {
    this.errors = [];
    for (var i in this.parentInfo) {
        if (this.parentInfo[i] === null && i !== 'secondaryPhone' || !this.parentInfo[i] && i !== 'secondaryPhone') {
            this.errors.push('All parent info must be filled out, with the exception of a Secondary Phone Number');
            return;
        }
    }

}
```

Is there a built in way to do my if statement? In one swoop like I can in C#?

Comment: you don't want your variable to contain whitespaces. Is it ri8?

Comment: Remember, Vue is still just JavaScript.

Comment: i didn't understand could you please tell me again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `if (this.parentInfo[i] === null)` you can easily write `if (!this.parentInfo[i])` which will be true when `this.parentInfo[i]` is anything but `undefined`, `null`, `NaN`, `0`, `""` (empty string) or `false`.

A string containing only a whitespace will return true, so you'll have to run `if (this.parentInfo[i]===" ")` for that.

You can of course create your own method `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` and use that instead.

Please also note that this is rather a Javascript question than a Vue.js question.

Comment: I was hoping there was a built in way, but what ever makes it work. Wouldn't it also be `if (!this.parentInfo[i])`?